# CSS change style of different element upon active

Tags: html, css, gumby-framework

Trying to change the content of an image by clicking another image (image gallery viewer), using pure HTML/CSS.

I am using the `gumby.css` [framework](http://gumbyframework.com/) and currently have the following HTML:

```
<section id="sect">
    <div class="three columns">
        <img src"/images/help.png">
    </div>
    <div class="one column">
        <img src"/images/help.png">
    </div>
</section>
```

And the following css:

```
#sect .three.columns img:hover {
    content:url("/images/about.png");
    border: 5px solid red;
}

#sect .one.column img:active ~ #sect .three.columns img {
    content:url("/images/about.png");
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

The first css rule for `#sect .three.columns img:hover` works perfectly, indicating I have selected the right element. But the second one `#sect .one.column img:active ~ #sect .three.columns img` does nothing upon active.

Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered) for the meaning of `~`.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: This isnt possible - CSS rules depend on degrees of decendancy and cannot traverse the DOM, by say, ascending up one parent level, then moving across and back down (in layman terms).

Comment: How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9AbvE/951/)? You can click the top red box and it will change the style (in this case colour) of the other box. It seems fine to me. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: Both `cube` elements are at the same 'level' - in your example, your images are nested.

Comment: I see. Can you suggest a simple alternative solution please?

Comment: Either make them be on the same level – or try applying the effect to the parent element instead.

Comment: As CBroe suggests, why not apply the :active to the parent element?

Comment: Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/ZLkXG/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this isnt possible in the way you are currently implementing.

CSS rules depend on degrees of decendancy and cannot traverse the DOM, by say, ascending up one parent level, then moving across and back down (in layman terms). They are limited to only identifying siblings and children.

The `content` style is also *only* available to `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

As such, the alternative would be to apply the operation to the `active` state of the parent elements, removing the child images, and referencing the `background-image` and not `content` property e.g.:

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/ZLkXG/1/)

HTML

```
<section id="sect">
    <div class="three columns"></div>
    <div class="one column"></div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.column, .columns {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-image:url(http://phaseoneimageprofessor.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/iqpw29_main_image_.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
}
.three.columns:hover ~ .one.column {
    border:1px solid red;
    background-image:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9c/Image-Porkeri_001.jpg);
}
```